# How to pass arguments to jvmmon?

Tags: java, performance, jboss, jvm

I am using jvmmon to collect dumps. But I have to enter parameters manually , I mean print stacktrace and thread dump path etc. Is there any way I can put all into a single line or one statement.

How it is now ?

```
jvmmon
> print to file
> print stacktrace
```

How I want ?

```
jvmmon <something> print to file <something else> print stacktrace
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using `jcmd` instead to run commands; but in any case, that will need to have two separate commands instead of one command to do two different operations.

Comment: Excellent,  this is what I need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this easily with below command.

```
printf "PID\nprint to file\n/tmp/traces/$file.txt\nprint stacktrace\nexit\n" | jvmmon
```